# Window title does not appear in chrome packaged-apps (Windows 7)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am creating a chrome window with the 'frame' option set to 'chrome' in the `CreateWindowOptions` argument.

Using Linux the window title appears in the frame however when using packaged-apps on Windows the title does not appear. This can be seen in the screen-shots attached.

[image: Linux Screenshot]
[image: Windows Screenshot]

**Update**

There has been some progress with this as can be seen from this Chromium Bug

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=225916

Answer (score 2):

We currently don't display the title inside the Window's title bar. We're considering whether to change this.

Comment: What is the latest thinking on changing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour. If you want to display a title, you should use a custom frame (`{frame: 'none'}` in the window create options).

Comment: The inconsistency across OSes is notable.

Comment: I think there should still be away to have a native platform frame look, maybe there should be an additional 'native' value for the 'frame' option. Yes, you can add a custom title in a frame-less window but you would also need to add window movement handlers and minimize/maximize/close buttons.. which I think its 'too much' work just to have a window title.. (on Windows)

Comment: I read the Chromium bug report in the OP's update, but I'm still confused about the thinking on this. What other application framework forces each individual developer to manually style a window frame, duplicating the effort the operating system has already done for you?

Comment: yes. However, Windows taskbar takes its text from the `<title>` tag !?!